# Binding click event through elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I need to know whether I am doing the best way of binding click event through elements in jQuery. I need to avoid duplicate code in my function (since lot of duplicate code is repeated in all functions).

How can I clean this up and do it in a better way?

```
 $(".nna-icon-excel").click(function (e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.parent().attr("href", "?excel=1")
                var href = $this.parent().attr("href");
                if (activeTab.toLowerCase() == "table") {
                    action = "expand";
                }
                else {
                    action = "expandheatmap";
                }
                $this.parent().attr("href", href + "&from=" + action + "&expand=" + Expand + "");
            });
            $(".nna-icon-pdf").click(function (e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.parent().attr("href", "?savehtml=1&openpdf=1&orientation=@ViewBag.PdfOrientation")
                var href = $this.parent().attr("href");
                if (activeTab.toLowerCase() == "table") {
                    action = "expand";
                }
                else {
                    action = "expandheatmap";
                }
                $this.parent().attr("href", href + "&from=" + action + "&tabactive=" + action + "&expand=" + Expand + "");
            });
            $(".gridoptions-anchor").click(function (e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.attr("href", "/home/xx/Index" + "/?columnchooser=1");
                var href = $(this).attr("href");
                var action = "";
                if (activeTab.toLowerCase() == "table") {
                    action = "expand";
                }
                else {
                    action = "expandheatmap";
                }

              $this.attr("href", href  + "&from=" +action + "&expand=" + Expand+ "");

            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the code could be tigher

- This

  ```
  var action = "";
  if  {
      action = "expand";
  }
  else {
      action = "expandheatmap";
  }
  ```

  could be reduced with a ternary operation to:

  ```
  var action = (activeTab.toLowerCase() == 'table') ? 'expand' : 'expandheatmap`;
  ```

  Since you repeat this in every handle, you should consider building a `function` for this, in case the logic ever changes.
- I am a bit confused by your code, you seem to build the href, get the href, modify that string and then set the href again ? Why ? The following should work in my mind ( I took the last click handler ) :

  ```
  $(".gridoptions-anchor").click(function (e) {
      var href = "/home/xx/Index" + "/?columnchooser=1"
      var action = (activeTab.toLowerCase() == 'table') ? 'expand' : 'expandheatmap`;
      $(this).attr("href", href  + "&from=" +action + "&expand=" + Expand + "");
  });
  ```
- This brings me to my next point; `activeTab`, `action`, and `Expand` are not defined with `var` in this code
- Finally you could consider a dedicated URL building function to have the string concatenation in one place:

  ```
  function buildURL( href, action, expand, addTabActive )
  {
    var tabActiveParameter = addTabActive ? ( '&tabactive=' + action ) : '';
    return href + "&from=" + action + "&expand=" + expand + tabActiveParameter;
  }
  ```
- Which brings me to my last point if `tabactive` shows the action, then `activetab` would be a better name.

Comment: whether am doing correct way of binding event to element? or need to use latest ".on" in jquery. i am bit confused about this binding technique. am i using standard way ?

Comment: Feel free to select this as the answer (green checkmark)

Comment: `.click()` is fine, just dont use `.live()`

Comment: Accepted!!! cheers!!!